# How to make link color change based on location on page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, zurb-foundation

I am working on a single-page website that has a navigation bar along the top, with internal links to various sections of the page. My goal is to have the links change color depending on where you are on the page; if you are in the “Top” section, then the link to “Top” would be black while all the others were green; if you were in the “Services” section, then the link to “Services” would be black while all the others were green, etc. Is this possible, and if so, how would I implement it using HTML, CSS, or jQuery? If it helps, I am using Foundation to structure my website. Excerpts of my code are below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();

    var splashOneHeight = $("div#splash-one").height();
    var servicesHeight = $("div#services").height();
    var splashTwoHeight = $("div#splash-two").height();
    var pricesHeight = $("div#prices").height();

    var firstFade = splashOneHeight - 50
    var secondFade = splashOneHeight + servicesHeight + 50
    var thirdFade = splashOneHeight + servicesHeight + splashTwoHeight
    var fourthFade = splashOneHeight + servicesHeight + splashTwoHeight + pricesHeight

    if (scrollDistance > 0) {
      $("nav").addClass("highlight");
    };
    if (scrollDistance == 0) {
      $("nav").removeClass("highlight");
    };

    if (scrollDistance >= 0 && scrollDistance < firstFade) {
      $("nav").css("opacity", '0.75');
    };
    if (scrollDistance >= firstFade && scrollDistance < secondFade) {
      $("nav").css("opacity", '0.96');
    };
    if (scrollDistance >= secondFade && scrollDistance < thirdFade) {
      $("nav").css("opacity", '0.75');
    };
    if (scrollDistance >= thirdFade && scrollDistance < fourthFade) {
      $("nav").css("opacity", '0.96');
    };
    if (scrollDistance >= fourthFade) {
      $("nav").css("opacity", '0.75');
    };
  });
})

jQuery(function($) {
  // from http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

  // Wicked credit to
  // http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/18/jquery-smooth-scroll-bugs.html
  var scrollElement = 'html, body';
  $('html, body').each(function() {
    var initScrollTop = $(this).attr('scrollTop');
    $(this).attr('scrollTop', initScrollTop + 1);
    if ($(this).attr('scrollTop') == initScrollTop + 1) {
      scrollElement = this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
      $(this).attr('scrollTop', initScrollTop);
      return false;
    }
  });

  // Smooth scrolling for internal links
  $("a[href^='#']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
      target = this.hash,
      $target = $(target);

    $(scrollElement).stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });

  });

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700);
 nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.75;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  width: 150px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}
nav ul li a {
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  color: #008040;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
nav.highlight {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DragonTech &mdash; Home</title>

  <link href="css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/rippler.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/filters.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="top" href="#splash-one">Top</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="services" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="prices" href="#prices">Prices</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="appointment" href="#splash-three">Contact us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: something like this maybe(idea add "black class" for the clikced element and remove this class for the others)?http://jsfiddle.net/e476r4uk/

Comment: @Amani this is a great solution to one part of my problem, but I also want the links to change color if you’ve just scrolled to that section, not clicked on it. It should really be location sensitive, not just click sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something very similar to this already in your JQuery, where you set the nav opacity based on the scroll position:

```
if (scrollDistance >= 0 && scrollDistance < firstFade) {
  $("nav").css("opacity", '0.75');
};
```

First, add an "active" class to your CSS:

```
 .active { 
   color: black;
 }
```

Then get the vertical scroll position of each div:

```
var splashOnePosition = $("div#splash-one").offset().top;
//etc, for the rest of your divs
```

Then, as you scroll, if your scrollDistance is greater than the divPosition, remove existing "active" classes, then add it to the correct div, e.g:

```
 if (scrollDistance > 0 && scrollDistance > splashOnePosition) {
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   $('div#splash-one").addClass('active');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just added a few codes on your script brother. Hope this will work on you.

**JS**

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('ul li a').removeClass( 'active-menu' );
    $(this).addClass( 'active-menu' );
    var $this = $(this),
      target = this.hash,
      $target = $(target);

    $(scrollElement).stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
    }); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul li a{color: #008040;}
ul li .active-menu{color:#000;}
```